# delete filenames including double quotes in Linux or Windows

Tags: filenames, double-quotes

i have the following list of files, that whindow is not capable to delete:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me the command to delete those files in windows command line or ubuntu subsystem in windows.

I tried single quotes or escaping with .
Nothing works.

Comment: Maybe they're not quotes but some kind of freaky unicode character?  Try hitting tab a few times and seeing what it says...good luck!

Comment: Any reason you can't use File Explorer to browse and delete?

Comment: Syntax isn't your problem, at least not your main problem. See all those question marks in the output of ll? Your Linux subsystem can't stat those files to get those attrs, and I believe that's why it can't delete them either. How is that filesystem mounted? Can you access any files under it? It's likely a permissions issue in the Windows FS, but I can't really guess much more than that.